# How to index custom url based on terms searched on Google

Tags: php, nginx, seo

Sometimes I see on Google links with my terms searched on Google as parameter. For example, if I search "StrangeWord", I can see in results:

```
example.com/p=StrangeWord
```

I'm pretty sure it is generated automatically, how to do it? I'm using PHP with Nginx.

Comment: I'm not a SEO guy, but I believe this is not done automatically. If google shows this result, it means that this page was crawled before. I think `example.com`'s owners have generated a lot of various pages with all kinds of words and word combinations in `GET`, and made google crawl them **before** you see the result

Comment: @Curious are you sure?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. That's why I wrote "I believe" and "I think" :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't generated automatically. If that page is in the index, it's because there was a crawlable link to that page - whether intentionally done by the webmaster or not - and Google happened to crawl that link.

Links can get generated by users sharing such a page, bookmarking it, or even linking to it from their own sites / social profiles